# SoQL Clause using starts with

Tags: socrata, soda

Is there a way to use STARTS WITH operator when writing a query string for the REST API?
For example:

```
http://data.cms.gov/resource/jzd2-pt4g.json?$where=keyword STARTS WITH 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know not necessarily a direct answer, but I was looking at trying to do this myself as well. Normally I would use the LIKE command in SQL to do what I want. The best I was able to come up with the SoQL was to query all the data for a specific value using the `$q=` operator. So, something like this would get the data you want that you were looking for with "Us exam" in the record (but not at the beginning, anywhere in the record):

```
http://data.cms.gov/resource/jzd2-pt4g.json?$q=%22Us%20exam%22
```